# Allow members to upload to my YouTube account

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I have seen this question out there but never a clear answer. I am looking for the ability to allow members of my site be able to upload videos through my site that will then be added to my YouTube account. All I can find are ways for users to upload videos through my website to **their** accounts. An example of this would be helpful if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For privacy issues, users have to upload videos into their accounts first. There is one way to get around it.

You can use [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/).

So user's would still upload their videos with their own credentials, but then you have to option to moderate and approve those videos to have them in your playlist.